# Push all postfix/exim mails to a shared folder

Tags: email, postfix-mta, exim

I am trying to setup a local email relay that a bunch of developers can use to test their applications against to send emails. This mail server should not be able to send emails anywhere, but rather put all emails that it receives into a folder which is shared via samba.

Then the developers can browse to that share and open their email from the share and look at it using outlook.

Have been searching all day on how to accomplish this, but still no where.
it can use postfix, exim or whichever other MTA.

I don't know where to start. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution using this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/661942/postfix-catch-all-email-save-to-combined-file).

Installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 stock standard, adding apt-get install postfix and apt-get install postfix-pcre (this pcre was the missing part, wihtout it, the script won't work)

Modified the script accordingly to my environment, restarted/reloaded postfix, installed samba and created a shared folder.

tested and all emails are placed in the folder configured in the script.